# Code Formatting in Two Consecutive Lines

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

#### What I see as an issue:

A lot of times when I read and write code in StackOverflow I run into the following scenario:

---

Here is some `Code` and words. This is more random wody stuff, `some code` suddenly a widd more some more  `Other Code` which makes the above code seems `Related` although it is not.

---

See how `Code` and `Other Code` seem visually related although they are not?

#### Possible solutions:

I actively try to avoid this when writing questions and answers, and it's no fun to read either. Since the two lines of text are in the same paragraph, adding another line between them or more spacing seems like a poor solution to me.

Possible approaches I came up with:

- Remove the `background-color` attribute from code that is in paragraphs. Which would produce:

[image: First Option]

- Add a white border (maybe thinner?) which would produce:

[image: border]

- Reduce the padding of code blocks inside tags which would look like

[image: padding]

For reference, here is the [original image as a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnUBH.png) , here is [how this sort of thing looks in GitHub.](https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/5612591)

Comment: Doesn't really look like a problem to me, I'm able to see the separation at least.

Comment: [This is how it looks to me](http://i.imgur.com/hUxN496.png)

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why the difference between http://i.imgur.com/hUxN496.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/OnUBH.png (What it looks like to me and what it looks like to eazimmerman)? I've tried disabling all extensions and setting zoom to 100%, I'm on Google Chrome on Windows, he's on Google Chrome on mac.

Comment: Just to be clear, there isn't a white gap between the two for me (ie, the borders merge), but it doesn't confuse me.  On Chrome for Windows.

Comment: Well you can avoid this of course by putting code into code blocks, when appropriate, instead of constantly trying to jam code into normal conversation.

Comment: @Joe This doesn't seem like an issue to you, which is a fair and valid point. My only complaint to you is that your comment is not an answer (Which would allow an accurate reading of how people agree or disagree with it).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I actively avoid this sort of thing, one way in which I do that is avoid this by putting code into code blocks, every once in a while you just want to mention a term in a language like `module.functionName` and the appearance in two consecutive lines seems confusing to me.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm fairly new to Meta, so wasn't sure if it was normal to make an answer for that or just include it in comments (since I'm not saying anything particularly interesting).  If I should write an answer for it I'm happy to :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it's "confusing" - if it's meant as part of the natural language of the paragraph, nobody should think the two words are related, even if CSS margins are not present. This is about pretty, I think, not confusion. Note that this doesn't happen on some other sites, like [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) where the font size for `<code>` is slightly smaller.

Comment: I see the same (no spacing) in all my browsers on a Mac, including in IE on Windows 7 running in Parallels. Slightly annoys me too.

Comment: ...and it's shown with spacing in the mobile theme, in those same browsers. I indeed like that much better.

Comment: I find this styling issue annoying as well. I'd prefer even a `border: 2px solid white` around every `<code>`; sometimes it looks a little weird but it's easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think this is a problem.  I'm able to parse code in the paragraph fine even if it does happen to line up that way.  The only fix that would be acceptable to me would be a slightly shrinking of the padding to keep a slight white space between; I don't think that's needed but it wouldn't bother me.  Any of the other ones would make code tags less useful for me.

Comment: At Benjamin's request, moved to an answer.